# VSCode flags methods in Angular CLI spec.ts files as errors

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, karma-jasmine

I am creating unit tests in the spec.ts files created by Angular CLI.  When I run `ng test` the tests run fine.  However, it's annoying that the VS Code editor flags all the text methods as errors.

```
it ('should create', () = {
  expect (component).toBeTruthy() ; Property 'toBeTruthy' does not exist on type 'Assertion'
}):
```

It does this for all of them, `toBeTruthy`, `toBe`, etc.

I assume there's some conf somewhere that I am missing.  Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: have you tried closing and re-opening vscode?  Also, are you using any Angular-related VSCode extensions?

Comment: Create new project and see how it generates tsconfig files

Comment: Further research says it might be a conflict between Jasmine and Cypress.  Most annoying.